# how to monitor the cpu usage of every code line in python program

Tags: python, cpu, monitor

Is there any monitor utils that can monitor the cpu usage of every code line use in python program.
I know profile,cProfile and line_profiler. but they are only statistic the time of each line or function using the cpu.
If my program is io-intensive, it may be use a long time but doesn't really use the calculation of the cpu.
So I want to find a util which could monitor the real calculation of the cpu.
Have anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cProfile` and `profile` both accept a time base function as a parameter.  Just pass `time.clock` instead of the default `time.time`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.if I run my script like this: python -m cProfile -o result.out server.py
how could I change the default time base function to time.clock?

Comment: Can't.  If you want to change the timer, you'll have to add the profiling code to your module.